# Fatal error.. Call to a member function.. on a non-object

Tags: php

I have a `GCM` class which includes a send_notification function. In a different class, `Demand.php`, I am trying to use the send_notification function. So I have a constructor in `Demand.php` which  points to my `GCM` class like this:

```
 $gcm = new GCM();
```

This `$gcm` variable is used in a function inside that class like this:

```
$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
```

That's where I get the error:

```
<br />n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function send_notification() on a non-object in..
```

I searched for the problem and found out that the problem is that `$gcm` is null and that's why it's calling nothing. So when I put the

```
$gcm = new GCM();
```

Inside my function it worked correctly. But is there no other way of doing this? I mean should it not be alright only by putting creating `$gcm` in the constructor of `Demand.php`?

Here are the parts where I am referring to:

```
function __construct() {
    require_once 'GCM.php';
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
    $gcm = new GCM();
    $df = new DB_Functions();

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}


public function getDistance($uuid, $name, $distance, $latstart, $lonstart, $latend, $lonend, $gcm_regId) {
    $user_new = array ("$uuid", "$name", "$distance","$latstart", "$lonstart", "$latend", "$lonend","$gcm_regId");  
    $query = sprintf("SELECT uid, distance,latstart, lonstart, latend, lonend, gcm_regid, name FROM user_demand WHERE latstart='%s' AND lonstart='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($latstart),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lonstart));
    $user = mysql_query($query);

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($user);

    while($user_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($user))
    {
        $djson = $this->findDistance($latend,$lonend,$user_old["latend"],$user_old["lonend"] );

        if ($user_old["distance"]+$distance>=$djson) {
            $match = mysql_query("INSERT INTO matched_users(gcm_a, gcm_b, name_a, name_b) VALUES(".$user_old['gcm_regid'].",".$user_new['gcm_regId'].",".$user_old['name'].",".$user_new['name'].")");
            $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regId);
            $message = array("var" => $name);
            $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a misunderstanding about scoping. Can you show us where you've put `$gcm = new GCM();` relative to `$gcm->send_n..`?

Comment: Do not discount debugging tools like Xdebug and var_dump , try those to see what values you have at that instant

Comment: `$gcm = new GCM();` will only exist in the current scope. You can set it to an instance variable so it can be accessed throughout the class: `$this->gcm = new GCM()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put `$gcm = new GCM();` in the constructor of your Demand class, then the variable `$gcm` will only be available in the constructor method.

If you want to be able to access the `$gcm` variable throughout the Demand class you'll need to set it as a property of the class like so:

```
class Demand()
{
    /**
     * Declare the variable as a property of the class here
     */
    public $gcm;

    ...
    function __construct()
    {
        ...
        $this->gcm = new GCM();
        ...
    }

    function myFunction()
    {
        ...
        // You can access the GCM class now in any other method in Demand class like so:
        $result = $this->gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked great, i am new in php, and i am missing basic knowledge, very helpful

Answer (score 3):

gcm will only be available in the scope of the constructor unless you initialize it as a instance variable.

```
class Demand
{
    private $_gcm; 
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_gcm = new GCM(); 
    }

    function youWantToUseGcmIn()
    {
        $this->_gcm->send_notification(.....); // access it like this 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, i am just new in php, and missing some basic knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

You create $gcm in an object constructor, then use it from some other method in the same class? You're not storing it properly, then. You have to do:

```
class X {
    function constructor() {
        $this->gcm = new GCM();
    }

    function other_method() {
        $this->gcm->send_notification(...);
    }
}
```

if you have

```
function constructor() {
    $gcm = new GCM();  <-- this is just a temporary local variable.
}
```

all you're doing is creating a local variable within the constructor, which will be destroyed as soon as the constructor returns. Saving the new object in $this->gcm saves it inside the containing object and makes it available to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

This means `$gcm` is not an object, probably it's NULL or false in some cases (nothing found) due to it's not accessible. Out of scope